# importing text files in R

Tags: r, eof

I exported results from the SEER database as a .txt file and I have been trying to import it into R for further recoding. The text file was created on Windows OS, and I am working on R on Mac OS X. I changed my working directory before trying to import, but it didn't work. I saw a thread here, which talked about this syntax for exporting .txt files:

```
students <- read.table(file.choose(), header=T, sep="\t")
```

I tried this too, but I got the same error message as before:

> Warning messages:
>   1: In scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
>     EOF within quoted string
>   2: In scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
>     number of items read is not a multiple of the number of columns

How do I get around this?

Comment: can you provide a snippet of the text file?

Comment: Hi, I had the same problem while trying to read a .tsv file into R. @Ekaba, your suggestion worked, but I want to know why and how? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try `read.delim(...)` instead of `read.table(...)`